# Converting flat array to tree structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, treeview

I have an issue with converting a flat array and could use your assistance!

Currently the data format is like this:

```
    [
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 1,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 8
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 3
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 10
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 1,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 8
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 3
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 10
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
        }
    ]
```

And I'm hoping to end up with a result like this:

```
    [
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                    "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                    "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
                    "MARKET_VALUE": 1,
                    "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 8,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 3
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                    "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                    "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
                    "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
                    "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                    "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                    "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
                    "MARKET_VALUE": 1,
                    "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 8,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "MAIN_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 3
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                    "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                    "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": null,
                    "MARKET_VALUE": 5,
                    "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 6,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ENTITY",
                            "SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME": "SECOND_ACCOUNT",
                            "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME": "TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2",
                            "MARKET_VALUE": 10,
                            "OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE": 5
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Apologies for the sheer size of it! The top level section will be MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME, level after that will be SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME and the lowest level items will TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME.

I've made numerous attempts to do this with lodash and vanilla javascript but have to concede that data manipulation is not really my area of skill and I'm struggling hard with it!

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me!

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific for your example data and you might need to tweak it if you have other data shape.

Yet it's not recommended if you have like 1000 item.

```js
function makeTree(data) {
  return data
    .filter(
      (masterItem) =>
        masterItem.SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME === null &&
        masterItem.TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME === null
    )
    .map((masterItem) => ({
      ...masterItem,
      children: data
        .filter(
          (subItem) =>
            subItem.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME === masterItem.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME &&
            subItem.SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME !== null &&
            subItem.TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME === null
        )
        .map((subItem) => ({
          ...subItem,
          children: data.filter(
            (tertiaryItem) =>
              tertiaryItem.SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME === subItem.SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME &&
              tertiaryItem.TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME !== null
          ),
        })),
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using javascript and lambdas to manipulate your array? Something like this:

```
const yourArray = [....];
const result = yourArray.filter(obj => obj['SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME'] == null);
result.forEach(node => node["CHILDRENS"] = yourArray.filter(obj => obj['SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME'] != null && obj['TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME'] == null && obj["MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME"] == node["MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME"]));
```

This create a two level structure.. now , to generate the third, you would need to do something similar for each second level node.. it could be generalized with a function.. something like this:

```
function putChildrenFromArray(nodes, elements, howToSelectSons) {
  nodes.forEach(node => node["CHILDRENS"] = elements.filter(obj => howToSelectSons(obj, node)));
}
```

calling it like this:

```
putChildrenFromArray(result, yourArray, (obj, father) => obj['SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME'] != null && obj['TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME'] == null && obj["MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME"] == father["MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME"])
```

and you could call it one for the second level.. then one once for each first level node, passing its childrens and, of course, changing the lambda / function used to select sons.

You should change minimal stuff between the two lambdas.. and you could generalize it even more if you can have even more levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `reduce` method with `while` loop and an array to store values on different levels that will be mapped from another `levels` object.

```js
const data = [{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":6,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":1},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":1,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":8},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1","MARKET_VALUE":10,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":5},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2","MARKET_VALUE":5,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":3},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":5,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":10},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1","MARKET_VALUE":6,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":1},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2","MARKET_VALUE":10,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":5},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":6,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":1},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":1,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":8},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1","MARKET_VALUE":10,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":5},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"MAIN_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2","MARKET_VALUE":5,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":3},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":null,"MARKET_VALUE":5,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":10},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_1","MARKET_VALUE":6,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":1},{"MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ENTITY","SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME":"SECOND_ACCOUNT","TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME":"TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_2","MARKET_VALUE":10,"OVERALL_MARKET_VALUE":5}]

const result = []
const levels = [
  'MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME',
  'SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME',
  'TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME'
]

data.reduce((r, e) => {
  let value = { ...e, children: [] }
  let level = levels.length

  while (level--) {
    if (e[levels[level]]) {
      r[level + 1] = value.children
      r[level].push(value)
      break
    }
  }

  return r;
}, [result])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This looks amazing and I can see the code snippet runs perfectly. For some reason, it's returning an error in my Angular project. It says "Cannot read property push of undefined". Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: Try to `console.log` level and also r[level] before `r[level + 1] = value.children` line.

Comment: console.log returns 2 for level and undefined for r[level]

Comment: Its not working because this code assumes that you have items in order  similar to what you have in the demo example where first there is item with `TERTIARY` and `SUB` equal null that will go to level `0`, then the item with no `TERTIARY` that will go to level 1, and then item with `TERTIARY` that will be level 2. Instead you have first item `TERTIARY` that should be level 2 and but there is no an array created for that level.

Comment: Basically if first you have an item with just `MASTER_ACCOUNT_NAME` that item will go on level 0 and it will create an array for the next level 1 which is an item with `SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME` but not for item with also `TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_NAME` which is level 2. Unless you can modify your data to add `id` and `parentId` on each item I'm not sure what logic you could use to define the `parent-child` connection other then correct order of items in the data + levels.

Comment: Hi again, thank you so much for keeping on this for me! Okay, so as you correctly surmised, the data that is being returned from the server is not maintaining a hierarchy, it's returning all the items in random order (I assumed it would be correctly ordered, I was given faulty info from the backend guys). I do however see that all the records have a MASTER_ACCOUNT_ID, SUB_ACCOUNT_ID and TERTIARY_ACCOUNT_ID. Not sure if this helps at all? No worries if not, I can have a chat with the backend guys if needs be.

Comment: If you want to use id's to create nested structure that would require different approach that this. Post your data with the correct structure if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212060/discussion-between-dozyhoneybadger-and-nenad-vracar).